# Angular Material Styling Disappearing

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

I have a material date range entry, and on it's own it looks fine. I have checked everything I can, however I am at a loss as I cannot see any reason for this to be the case.

```
    <p>Works</p>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="z1">
    <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
        <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" [(ngModel)]="start">
        <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" [(ngModel)]="end">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY – MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-button (click)="search()">Search</button>
<!--<mat-form-field>
    <mat-table></mat-table>
</mat-form-field>-->
```

gives me
[image: Screenshot showing formatted daterange box]

However, uncommenting the table, with or without the form field, removes that formatting.

```
<p>Works</p>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="z1">
    <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
        <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" [(ngModel)]="start">
        <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" [(ngModel)]="end">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY – MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-button (click)="search()">Search</button>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-table></mat-table>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

For reference, this is my imports.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PrintBookingComponent,
    PrintBookingDetailsComponent,
    OrderSearchComponent,
    OrderBookingComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatIconModule,
    BrowserModule,
    GraphQLModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ApolloModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_FLAGS,
      useValue: {
        useInitialLoading: true, // enable it here
      },
    },{
    provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
    useFactory: (httpLink: HttpLink) => {
      return {
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        
        link: httpLink.create({
          uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql/',
        }),
      };
    },
    deps: [HttpLink],
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[StackBlitz link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3mk4mh?file=src%2Fapp%2Forder-search%2Forder-search.component.html)

Comment: can u share your code on stackblitz; probably there is a class css overided when you use the mat-table

Comment: And can u share us your console in question ? I think u don't import mat table module . Just my guess . So, I need to see your console.

Comment: A mat-form-field can **not** inside a mat-table else a mat-label, a mat-input (optional a mat-icon and a mat-hint), see the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

Comment: It doesn't matter if I just add the table or include the matfield around it. See the stackblitz example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all don't wrap with `mat-form-field` because `mat-form-field` work only with form like `input, button` etc. Then add `dataSource, row, header, column` like below code

HTML: `

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.position }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.weight }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.symbol }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

`

TS:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = [
    {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
    {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
    {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
    {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
    {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
    {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
    {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
    {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
    {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
    {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
```

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz with the corrected html, and it seems to work now. It wasn't clear from the errors I was originally getting what the problem was.

Comment: I really still don't know why my answer wasn't the correct one ever even I showed them with evidence which are corrected. So sad ^-^.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your stackblitz . Please check it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hhofab?file=src%2Fapp%2Forder-search%2Forder-search.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Forder-search%2Forder-search.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Forder-search%2Forder-search.component.scss

**Evidence**

[image]

Comment: It is, I've added a stackblitz link to the question

Comment: Ok. Please wait a minute.

Comment: Oh! I see you need to add some mat column , header and row def. Mat table can't use like that only.

Comment: Please wait a minute again. I will add it for you in that stackblitz.

Comment: I did that the first time I got the error, I removed them trying to get to the minimum repro scenario.

Comment: Do you want to add a mat table in that screen ? Am I right ?

Comment: I have updated your stackblitz . Please check it in my answer.