# Value is not displaying in mat table datasource

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to set datasource for mat table. but when i am printing the value in console it is coming as a object.

```
this.orderPicked = 'Orders Picked';
 this._httpservice.getOrderList().subscribe((response: any) => {
   this.orderList = response.content;
    Object.entries(response.content).forEach(([key, value]) => {
     this.ordersMap.set(key, value as Array<String>);
   });
   this.ordersMap.get( this.orderPicked).map(value => {
     this.availableOrdersDatasource = [value];
   });
 }, error => {
   this.errorDetails = error;
 });
```

Comment: Check below URL, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72854363/angular-material-styling-disappearing/72855284

Comment: If i convert value as [value] it is taking only one input. it is not looping further values in map

Comment: Can you create a example project in https://stackblitz.com ?